# Django and Google Apps users authentication

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-apps

I want to integrate Google Apps into my django application and I need that all Google Apps users could log in. There are plenty of solutions but all of them are meant just for one domain or a limited number of domains. But that's not enough for me, I want to implement SSO and therefore I have to be able to grant access to users from all Google Apps domains.

All solutions I have found are missing only the first step of authenticating process: it means to take the given domain and find location of appropriate XRDS file. I saw it written in PHP and it wouldn't be difficult to do the same thing in Python. However, it would be useless to write it again if there is a working solution somewhere.

Could you recommend me something?

Answer (score 1):

Use App Engine's [OpenID support](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview.html) in conjunction with [Google Apps Marketplace](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/sso.html).

Comment: Of course, I know about this, but I would like to use some special django features (groups, permissions etc) and it wouldn't be possible with pure App Engine code. I really need to 'integrate' Google Apps users into django's authentication system.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Django App that seems pretty suited to your situation: https://github.com/hudora/django-googleappsauth/

Only downside is the comments within the code are in German, but I've not found it too hard to follow with the help of Google Translate and the Readme covers most parts.